# How many times is it recorded in scripture - instances where Jesus ate a meal?

Tags: life-of-jesus, bible

I could only think of five meals:
1. Last supper
2. Wedding Reception/Water into Wine
3. Multiplied the boys lunch for the multitudes
4. Zacchaeus called down from tree
5. Before Jesus ascended by the lake;Peter jumped off the fishing boat and Jesus ate fish.

How awesome would that breakfast be! Praise The Lord

Comment: There were actually two occurrences of lunch multiplication: 5000 men + women and children in Mt 14, and 4000 men + women and children in Mt 15.

Comment: There are also two meals in Lk 24, after the resurrection, with two different groups of disciples.

Comment: List questions are usually very good for this site.

Comment: Don't forget meals associated with the Feast of Unleavened Bread, The Feast of Pentecost, and the Feast of Tabernacles. He also know he attended the Feast of Dedication AKA Hanukkah.

Answer (score 6):

**How many times recorded in scripture; instances where Jesus ate a meal?**

*“The Son of Man has come eating and drinking, and you say, ‘Look, a glutton and a drunkard, a friend of tax collectors and sinners!’”* (Luke 7:34)

- In Luke and Matthew, it is only all too obvious that Jesus ate after his [Temptation in the Desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temptation_of_Christ) (Luke 4:1–13) and (Matthew 4:1–11).
- In John 2, Jesus is at the Wedding Feast at Cana (2:1-11).
- In Luke 5, Jesus eats with tax collectors and sinners at the home of Levi (5:29-32).
- In Luke 7, Jesus is anointed by a woman in the home of Simon the Pharisee during a meal (7:36-50).
- In Luke 9, Jesus feeds the five thousand (9:10-36).
- In Matthew 14, Jesus feeds 5000 with two barley loaves and two fish. (Mt 14:13-21).
- In Luke 10, Jesus eats in the home of Mary and Martha (10:25-42).
- In Luke 14, Jesus shares about the parable of the large banquet in which He urges people to invite the poor rather than their friends (14:7-24).
- In Luke 19, it is implied that Jesus ate with Zacchaeus and his household (19:1-10).
- In Luke 22, we read the account of the Last Supper (22:14-23).
- In Luke 24, states that Jesus stayed and had supper with the two disciples after the encounter on the road to Emmaus (24: 13-35).
- In Luke 24, there is a second occurrence of Jesus eating after his resurrection. This time with his disciples in Jerusalem (14:35-48).
- In John 21, Jesus ate fish with his disciples after his resurrection and the miraculous catch of 153 fish (21:1-14).

Comment: "Look, a glutton and a drunkard" +1 just for mentioning that line! :)